# What is direct memory?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I am very much unclear that what is direct memory , Why it is designed in computer Architecture .

Can someone please explain, although it looks like very basic question , but still since i am not getting it, i am asking it. Please answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Direct Memory Access (DMA) is not Access of Direct Memory, but Direct Access of Memory (accesing main memory by a device, bypassing the CPU).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a basic question, but it's not really a common term. Perhaps it's defined in your textbook or class notes. If it were really so fundamental, you would be able to find it on Google.

Most computers have some *main memory* which is directly connected to the CPU by a *memory bus*. The most common type of memory used for this is DRAM, but the *D* stands for *dynamic*, not *direct*.

In CISC (complex instruction set computer) coding of instructions, the operand to an operation may be loaded from an address in memory which is directly specified in the immediate instruction. However, this terminology would be specific to a particular instruction set; it's not part of architecture in general.